# Laravel 5.6 Or Query Multiple in where

Tags: laravel

This is my filter query function

```
 $keywords = [];
       foreach($columns as $key => $value){
         $keywords[] = [$key, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%'];
        }
        $query= $this->model ->orderBy('name', 'asc')->where('is_deleted', 0)->Where($keywords);

        if($status=="yes")
             $query= $query->where('status',1);

         $query= $query->get();
         return $query;
```

For the above function, i got the following query

select * from `stores` where `is_deleted` = 0 and `status` = 1 AND (`name` LIKE %r% AND `address` LIKE %r%) order by `name` asc

But i need Or instead of ANd in the like query

```
select * from `stores` where `is_deleted` = 0 and `status` = 1 AND (`name` LIKE %r% or `address` LIKE %r%) order by `name` asc
```

Please tell in which place i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You have to group those `orWhere()` queries in one `where()` clause

```
$query = $this->model->where([
    ['is_deleted' => 0],
    ['status' => $status]
])
->where(function ($query) use($columns) {

    foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
        $query->orWehre($key, 'like', "%$value%");
    }
})
->orderBy('name');
```

Comment: If use tje above query i got the following error message undefined variable $columns

Comment: ofcourse I'm sorry, there is a mistake. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Where and orWhere.

```
$query= $this->model->orderBy('name', 'asc')->where('is_deleted', 0)->
        orWhere($key, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
```